# Comparing DATETIME MySQL column with php year

Tags: php, mysql, date, datetime

I have a table that holds items with a `created_at` `DATETIME` type column. I would like to return all items that were made in 2013.

I think I could do:

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
WHERE `created_at` > '2012' AND `created_at` < '2014'
```

But I would ideally like to be able to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
WHERE `created_at` = '2013'
```

I think this fails because it looks for items with a `DATETIME` of 2013-01-01 00:00:00. Is there a way to do it by converting the MySQL `created_at` to a year when comparing?

Comment: Year(created_at) ? You know, there IS a manual for this stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`year`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year) function for `created_at` column

```
WHERE YEAR(`created_at`) = '2013'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM items WHERE YEAR(created_at) = 2013
```

Reference: [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_year)

Answer (score 1):

use DATE_FORMAT mysql function.

```
SELECT * FROM `items`
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(created_at, ,'%Y') = '2013'
```